# How to count the values in column and save each column name with their result in a row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was making the database for some private site. In my database I have a table named times where I can save the usernames and the times when the user is free. The table looks like this.

```
|uid |Monday|Tuesday |... |Saturday |Sunday |t12|t13|t14|...|t19|t20
_____________________________________________________________________
```

The *uid* is the username and *t12-t20* are the hours ( ***t16* = 1**, ***monday* = 1** would mean that the user is free on monday at 16).

The **example** of one row would be:

```
|alex1|1|1|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|1|1|
```

That would mean that the user *alex1* is free on monday, tuesday and on sunday at 17, 18, 19 and 20 o'clock.

I can have multiple users in the table and multiple times for some users. Like, the user alex1 can be in more rows with different saved times. 
(**Example**: one row means that he is free on monday and friday after 15 but in some other row is he free on saturday at 14 and at 17 and at 20)

**Example**:

```
gordon | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
gordon | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

First row would mean: User gordon is free at 12 o'clock on Monday and Tuesday second row means: User gordon is free at 13 o'clock on Wednesday

The question is:

How can I make a query that goes trough the table and gives me the result:

```
  Day    | t12 | t13 | t14 | t15 | t16 | t17 | t18 | t19 | t20 |
________________________________________________________________
Monday      5     4     8     8     8     4     0     0     4
Tuesday     2     2     2     2     2     1     0     0     2
Wednesday   10    10    10    2     8     10    8     7     7
Thursday    5     4     8     8     8     4     0     1     4
Friday      5     4     3     7     8     4     9     0     4
Saturday    8     9     8     3     9     4     3     0     4
Sunday      1     4     8     8     1     4     0     9     3
```

That would mean: On monday at 14 o'clock there are 8 users that are free, or on friday at 20 there are 4 users which are free.

Comment: This makes no sense.  What if a user is free at noon on Monday and Tuesday, but not Wednesday.  And then free on Wednesday at 13:00.  How is this repesented?

Comment: first row: [gordon | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0 |]    

second row: [gordon | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0 |]    

first row means: User gordon is free at 12 o'clock on Monday and Tuesday    
second row means: User gordon is free at 13 o'clock on Wednesday

Comment: Note that a database table is NOT a spreadsheet. Redesign your schema. (Besides, in any event, this is a ridiculous design)

Comment: @Strawberry, how can I make it better?

I am not very good with databases and for me it would take too long to get a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

One example of a better design would be to have a table as follows:

`availability`

```
user day time
   1   1   16
```

This might not be the best solution, but it's a vast improvement on your current setup.

Comment: You solution is a better one and I think that I will do it in your way. 
I made a database like a spreadsheet where I use just 0's and 1's because I wanted to do some stuff with matix in background but I think I can do it in this way too. :) It will provide more backend programming, but I think that the queries in my database will be much more efficient. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can calculate day wise results and then use union all as below-

```
SELECT 'Monday' AS Day,
SUM(t12) t12,SUM(t13) t13,SUM(t14) t14,SUM(t15) t15,SUM(t16) t16,
SUM(t17) t17,SUM(t18) t18,SUM(t19) t19,SUM(t20) t20
FROM your_table WHERE Monday = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Tuesday' AS Day,
SUM(t12) t12,SUM(t13) t13,SUM(t14) t14,SUM(t15) t15,SUM(t16) t16,
SUM(t17) t17,SUM(t18) t18,SUM(t19) t19,SUM(t20) t20
FROM your_table WHERE Tuesday = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Wednesday' AS Day,
SUM(t12) t12,SUM(t13) t13,SUM(t14) t14,SUM(t15) t15,SUM(t16) t16,
SUM(t17) t17,SUM(t18) t18,SUM(t19) t19,SUM(t20) t20
FROM your_table WHERE Wednesday = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Thursday' AS Day,
SUM(t12) t12,SUM(t13) t13,SUM(t14) t14,SUM(t15) t15,SUM(t16) t16,
SUM(t17) t17,SUM(t18) t18,SUM(t19) t19,SUM(t20) t20
FROM your_table WHERE Thursday = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Friday' AS Day,
SUM(t12) t12,SUM(t13) t13,SUM(t14) t14,SUM(t15) t15,SUM(t16) t16,
SUM(t17) t17,SUM(t18) t18,SUM(t19) t19,SUM(t20) t20
FROM your_table WHERE Friday = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Saturday' AS Day,
SUM(t12) t12,SUM(t13) t13,SUM(t14) t14,SUM(t15) t15,SUM(t16) t16,
SUM(t17) t17,SUM(t18) t18,SUM(t19) t19,SUM(t20) t20
FROM your_table WHERE Saturday = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Sunday' AS Day,
SUM(t12) t12,SUM(t13) t13,SUM(t14) t14,SUM(t15) t15,SUM(t16) t16,
SUM(t17) t17,SUM(t18) t18,SUM(t19) t19,SUM(t20) t20
FROM your_table WHERE Sunday = 1
```

Comment: This actually works fine. I thought that this solution will be really slow but I tested it with bigger tables and I got the results really fast. :) 

Thank you :)

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked as i was upset getting a down vote for this answer :) If this really helped, can you please mark this as accepted @phpetista ?